# Finding the joint mgf of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let the joint pdf of $(X, Y)$ be given by
>
> $$f(x, y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \text{exp}\left(-y-\frac{(x -
>  y)^{2}}{2}\right) \hspace{1cm} \text{ for } y > 0, -\infty < x <
>  \infty$$
>
> Find the joint mgf of $X$ and $Y$.

**My attempt:**

Recall that every joint probability distribution function can be decomposed into the product of a marginal density and a conditional density. That is, we can write

$$f(x, y) = f_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y) \cdot f_{Y}(y).$$

Defining $f_{X \mid Y}(x\mid y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \text{exp}(-(-x-y)^{2}/2)$ and $f_{Y}(y) = \text{exp}(-y)$ works.

Now, note that $X | Y$ follows a normal distribution with parameters $y$ and $1$. Also, $Y$ follows an exponential distribution with parameter $1$. Therefore,

$$M_{X, Y}(s, t) = M_{X \mid Y}(s) \cdot M_{Y}(t) $$

$$= \frac{\text{exp}(ys + s^{2}/2)}{1 - t} $$

for $t < 1$.

---

Is my solution right? If not, what is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: It's a 2D normal distribution. Try completing the squares inside the exponential function first, then directly apply the mgf for multivariate normal.

Comment: The joint MGF should be a function of two variables

Comment: I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly deduced that $$X\mid Y\sim\mathcal N(Y,1)\quad,\text{ where }Y\sim\text{Exp}(1)$$

So the MGF of $(X,Y)$ should be

\begin{align}
M(s,t)&=E\,(e^{sX+tY})
\\&=E\left[E\,(e^{sX+tY}\mid Y)\right]
\\&=E\left[e^{tY}E\,(e^{sX}\mid Y)\right]
\\&=E\left[e^{tY}e^{sY+s^2/2}\right]
\\&=e^{s^2/2}\,E\left[e^{(t+s)Y}\right]
\\&=\frac{e^{s^2/2}}{1-(s+t)}\quad,\,s+t<1
\end{align}

The formula that you used, namely $M_{X, Y}(s, t) = M_{X \mid Y}(s) \cdot M_{Y}(t)$, doesn't make much sense.